# What electrodes to use to minimise corrosion during water electrolysis?

Tags: water, electrolysis

I did the $\ce{H2O}$ electrolysis experiment a few times, but every time a huge amount of the oxygen reacted with its corresponding electrode. What material should the electrode be made of in order to maximise the amount of oxygen I get?

Comment: a platinum electrode would be inert in such an electrolysis experiment.

Comment: Graphite electrodes also work quite well, they can be found in pencils and if they by any chance do erode, they can be replaced cheaply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the electrolyte as well as the electrode material. For example, $\ce{NaCl}$ releases atomic chlorine at the positive electrode, quickly attacking most materials except metals of the $\ce{Pt}$ group, as @MaxW mentions.

$\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{KOH}$ are a bit gentler on the electrodes. Run the apparatus at a low over-voltage to avoid damaging them. [Coated nickel electrodes](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0360319984900569) are suggested for use with alkaline solutions.

[Phosphoric acid is also suggested as an electrolyte.](http://papers.sae.org/670851/)